# Breadcrumbs for tiles 1 without struts

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tiles

using tiles 1 but not struts and wondering what's the best way to go about making dynamic breadcrumb links ?  Would it be simpler to just hardcode that part? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what framework are you using as a Controller but I suppose you have one.

In this case, you only need to define a controller URL (using the `controllerUrl` attribute) that can attend requests. Once you have it you need to use it and set in the tiles definition the properties needed to identify the navigation level for each page and where has to point every link.

This article can help you as a example:

http://www.calandva.com/holmansite/do/myblog/blogging?date=20030711

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cougil thanks man... Can u plz elaborate little bit.. liked your approach